# Python module import redefining namespace/__repr__ for refactoring

Tags: python, django

I Am trying to refactor my code for a series of Django models, but this is valid for general python imports.  Let me explain my setup and problem (with completly fake classes etc)

```
APP_ROOT/
|- __init__.py
|- tests/
|- urls.py
|- models/
|    |- __init__.py
|    |- BunchOfModels.py
|    |- SomeMoreModels.py
\- admin.py
```

in `models.__init__`:

```
# models/__init__.py
from APP_ROOT.models.BunchOfModels import *
from APP_ROOT.models.SomeMoreModels import *
```

this allows me to do the following:

```
from APP_ROOT.models import SuperModel
# Where SuperModel is in SomeMoreModels
```

The problem is that the class **repr** is:

`<class 'project.APP_ROOT.models.SomeMoreModels.SuperModel'>`
which messes up the foreign keys.

**my question**:

Is there a way to do this so that all my classes have a repr more like:
`<class 'project.APP_ROOT.models.SuperModel'>` without manually overloading the `__repr__` for each class.  I'm not even sure that this would solve the problem, and even if it did, This wouldn't port very well.

or do i need to go back to using one big, ugly file...

Comment: Django doesn't recommend you to spread your models on several files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already commented, Django doesn't recommend you to spread your models on several files. But this can solve your problem

```
from django.db import models

class SuperModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'APP_ROOT'
```

`app_label` attr should be in `Meta` class inside every model. You also can [inherit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance) `Meta` from base metaclass.

Other approach could be moving managers, utility function outside `models.py` (if you have them). But in this case you likely will get circular import.